# Why Chamakam is part of Srirudram?

Tags: yajur-veda, shukla-yajurveda

I am very much confused about Srirudram and Satarudriya.

I understand the Satarudriya. It is the 16th chapter of Shukla Yajuveda, which contains verses for Rudradevata. In Mahidhara's commentary, it is mentioned as Satarudriya or Rudradhyaya.

My confusion is about the Srirudram. Shukla Yajurveda chapters 16 (namakam) and 18 (chamakam) comprise Srirudram. Now, the questions are

1. Wherefrom we get the name "Srirudram"?
2. Chapter 18 has the mantras for Vasordhara homa. It does not specifically talk about Rudra Devata. In that case, why it is part of Srirudram?